# Check if variable exist in specific array key (PHP, MYSQLI)

Tags: php, arrays, search

EDIT: SOLVED - works as expected. Issue was with $search variable. Thanks for all of your help.

I have a typical WHILE that looks like this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
```

In my $row, I have a user_name key that looks like $row["user_name"].

I have a variable called $search.

Theoretically, $search could be in another key in the $row array, for example is could also be in $row["user_id"].

I'm trying to use stripos to see if there's a non-case-sensitive instance where $search is "like", or in the key, $row["user_name"].

I've even tried storing $row["user_name"] in a separate variable.

Basically.

```
if(stripos($row["user_id"],$search) !== false){
echo("working");
}
```

This never happens. Please help!

Edit:
Let me rephrase.

All I need to do is see if the $row["user_name"] CONTAINS what's in the string variable $search.

I've tried to convert $row["user_name"] into an array, a string, etc and tried in_array and stripos and nothing works.

The below will work:

```
if (stripos("hey you guys","guys")){
    echo("worked");
    }
```

But what I need is

```
if (stripos($row["user_name"],$search)){
    echo("worked");
    }
```

Edit:
var_dump looks like
array(2) { ["user_id"]=> string(3) "133" ["user_name"]=> string(3) "mrp" }

Edit:
I already verified that both $row["user_name"] and $search are strings so I don't get the issue.

Comment: Have you `var_dump` row? What keys are there, what values?

Comment: Its pretty Unclear. Can you post your inputs along with expected output

Comment: @aldrin27 I tried that and it not only doesn't work but if another column in my result set contained $search it would return true and I only want it to look at what is in $row["user_name"]. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $search = 'bar';
    $row = array('id' => 'fOo', 'name' => 'BAr', 'troll' => 'zer');

    // Method 1: preg_match
    $ret = (bool)preg_match('`(' . implode('|', array_values($row)) . ')`i', $search);

    // Method 2: array_search
    $ret = array_search(strtolower($search), array_map('strtolower', $row)) !== false;

    if ($ret) {
      echo 'found';
    } else {
      echo 'not found';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Navid but didn't work for me. I edited my original question to hopefully make more sense.

Comment: Can you edit your first post by adding the result of the following code inside your while: **var_dump($row)**

Comment: array(2) { ["user_id"]=> string(3) "133" ["user_name"]=> string(3) "mrp" }

Comment: If i changed in my answer it worked with the following: $search = 'mrp'; and 
$row = array("user_id"=>"133","user_name"=>"mRp");
So i think you miss a semi-colon. Put a bigger block of your code

Answer (score 0):

When you use `fetch_assoc`, it returns not an array, but an object.
So try different syntax:

```
stripos($row->user_id, $search)
```

Comment: I tried if (stripos($row->user_id, $search) !== FALSE) and still nothing.

Answer (score -1):

```
$string = str_replace($search,"",$row['user_id']);
$ctr = count($string);
   if($ctr>0) {echo 'found!';}
   else {echo 'not found!';}
```